# Is redefining arguments bad for optimisation?

Tags: javascript, optimization

Is redefining arguments bad for optimisation ?

For example :

```
function drawPic( id_pic , x , y )
{
    if( settings.round_coordinates==true )
    {
        x = Math.round(x);
        y = Math.round(y);
    }
    ...
}
```

I am used to do this, so convenient, but I wonder if I should not.

Comment: Every single statement, including variable assignments, takes (albeit extremely tiny amounts) some time to run. The less your program needs to do, the faster it will be.

Comment: @AndrewL., I'm not sure I get what you are saying here... did you mean *arguments* instead of *parameters* ? Then OP is processing the value of the arguments, he couldn't do it without the arguments. To OP, for optimisation, you'll will just avoid the definition of two more variables, which is just fine IMO, but which is also *tiny-micro-optimisation that you'll never notice*. Just write it the more readable as possible.

Comment: I mean arguments yes, but in the code in the question, he doesn't confirm or show that he's actually using the value of the arguments passed. It seems like he just reassigns them, which could make them redundant as in they shouldn't be arguments

Comment: Oh, can't believe I missed that. You're right @Kaiido

Comment: Of course the arguments will be used, but the rest of the function is not important here and it's just an example anyway, that is why I just wrote "...". In the example it is a drawing function, sometimes I may or not want it to round coordinates before drawing. The point of testing and rounding in the function is not having to do this before every call to the function. Instead of changing the arguments value I could use temporary variables in the function but that would create garbage. My question is : could it keep the function from being optimized or make it a lot slower ?